# Prove boundedness of a given entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, periodic-functions, complex-dynamics

For a non-constant transcendental  entire function $f$ and distinct constants $a$ and $b,$

suppose that $f(z)-az$ and $f(z)-bz$ are periodic with periods $x$ and $y$ respectively.

I have to show that $f(z)-az$ and $f(z)-bz$ are both bounded on a straight line $\{tx: t\in (-∞ , +∞)\}$.

Attempt:  since $f(z)-az$ and $f(z)-bz $ are periodic with periods $x$ and $y$ respectively, we find that $f'(z)$ has periods $x$ and $y$ and hence either $x/y$ is a real number or $f'(z)$ is a constant. But I can reject the latter case since $f(z)$ is given to be transcendental. But my problem is how this leads to the conclusion that $f(z)- az$ and $f(z)- bz$ are both bounded on a straight line $\{tx: t\in (-∞ , +∞)\}$.

I am stuck here.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking the right question? There is actually no function $f(z)$ satisfying the conditions you give.

Comment: @Zarrax's comment aside, you've already proved $x$ and $y$ are collinear, so wlog there is some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ where $y = \lambda x$. This means that $f(z) - az$ is a smooth periodic function on the straight line $\{tx\}$ and that $f(z) - bz$ is a smooth periodic function on the straight line $\{t \lambda x\}$, with the two lines being the same. And smooth periodic functions on a line are automatically bounded...

Comment: Every bounded entire function is constant...

Comment: @ Willie Wong can you please elaborate how periodic functions on a line are bounded?

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous and periodic functions of period $T$ on $\mathbb R$, it is bounded on the compact interval $[0,T]$ (extreme value theorem) and by periodicity  it extends to $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, the assumptions imply that $f'$ is periodic with periods $x$ and $y$. For a non-constant entire function, the only possibilities for the set of periods is either $\{0\}$ or $\omega \mathbb{Z}$, where $\omega \ne 0$ is some primitive period. In particular, this implies that $x=k\omega$ and $y=l \omega$ with some non-zero integers $k$ and $l$. Then $p = kl \omega$ is a common period of $f(z)-az$ and $f(z)-bz$, which implies that it is also a period of their difference $(b-a)z$. However, since this is not a periodic function, there is no such $f$.